# I have a JSON file which has multiple objects which I'm not able to [arse

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a JSON file in following format:

```json
{
  "product": {
    "loose_item1": {
      "gtin": "3011973",
      "numberOfUnits": "2",
      "unitOfMeasure": "EA"
    },
    "loose_item2": {
      "gtin1": "00218510000000"
    }
  }
```

I have written the following code to parse the above JSON, but I'm not able to access gtin, numberOfUnits, unitOfMeasure. I'm only able to access lose_item1, but I'm not able to iterate inside it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("/Users/mohitjoshi/Desktop/Tills-Karate-Automation-Test 2/src/test/java/com/tills/e2e/karate/template/masterData.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject name = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("product");
        Object level = name.get("loose_item1");
        Object level1 = level.get("gtin");
        System.out.println(level1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean you can't access it? Do you get an error (if so please provide exact error message)? No output?

Answer (score 0):

The Jackson library can do this.

```java
@Test
void test() throws Exception
{
    var source = """
            {
                "product": {
                "loose_item1": {
                    "gtin": "3011973",
                    "numberOfUnits": "2",
                    "unitOfMeasure": "EA"
                },
                "loose_item2": {
                    "gtin1": "00218510000000"
                }
                }
            }""";

    var om = new ObjectMapper();
    var json = om.readTree(source);
    var product = json.get("product");
    System.out.println("json.loose_item1.gtin: " + product.get("loose_item1").get("gtin"));
    System.out.println("json.loose_item2.gtin1: " + product.get("loose_item2").get("gtin1"));
}
```

Print the `level` in console or give a debug breakpoint to check out what is it. Or you may need to check the data in that file.

Comment: Hi @Firok Could you provide similar solution in java and instead of storing JSON in a string can we parse it from a .json file

Comment: @MohitJoshi Yes, code above is in Java 17. Replace the `source` from `String`  into any `java.io.File` instance then you could read data from files.